# Check on which page specific result exist

Tags: wp-query

I have a `$term_id = 123` and I want to find out on which page this term appears in the pagination. For example, we have:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'hello',
    'offset'       => $offset,
    'number'       => 10, // total per page
    'hide_empty' => false,
);

$term_query = new WP_Term_Query( $args );
```

And we get 1000 returned terms with 10 being displayed on each page. How do I find out on which page `$term_id` exists?

Obviously, I can loop through all results and do a `$term->term_id == $term_id` match and make a note of the iteration key, *but* I am hoping there is a more viable approach...?

While my case is specific to `WP_Term_Query()`, this should apply to querying other object like posts etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select this term_id from the DB and add row number column in SQL Query and then you can calculate in which page it should be.

For example:

```
global $wpdb;
$wanted_term = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT terms.* FROM (
    SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, t.*, tt.taxonomy
    FROM wp_terms AS t
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
    ON t.term_id = tt.term_id, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS r
    WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('hello') /* replace taxonomy */
) AS terms WHERE terms.term_id=123 /* replace term_id */ ORDER BY terms.name ASC");
```

And calculate with PHP.

```
$terms_per_page = 10;
$term_in_page = ceil($wanted_term->rownum / $terms_per_page);
```

Update SQL Query to have meta key, object_ids and order by meta value

```
SELECT allterms.* FROM (
    SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rownum, terms.* FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.taxonomy, tt.term_taxonomy_id, tm.meta_key, tm.meta_value, tr.object_id
        FROM wp_terms AS t
        INNER JOIN wp_termmeta AS tm ON ( t.term_id = tm.term_id )
        INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
        INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('fn_release') /* replace taxonomy */
        AND tr.object_id IN (108) /* replace object_ids */
        AND ( tm.meta_key = 'ma_tsms' )
        ORDER BY tm.meta_value+0 DESC
    ) AS terms, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS r
) AS allterms WHERE allterms.term_id=2543 /* replace term_id */
```

Query took 0.0020 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't this query *all* terms, making it quite a heavy query?

Comment: @ChristineCooper Hi, I didn't tested it with a large DB but from what I see its faster than the other option to get all terms and then to filter in php the term_id... Try both options and see what work for you faster. If you are using pagination its mean you already run the `get_terms` and get all the terms I think you need to check this and maybe use the same results so you could just filter.

Comment: @ChristineCooper See my answer I added the query that you wanted..

Comment: Thank you for the updated query (works fine). Although the calculation `ceil($wanted_term->rownum / $total_pages);` doesn't give correct page number. Note that `wp_count_terms()` gives total terms and not total pages. I also tried by calculating `ceil($wanted_term->rownum / ($total_pages / 10));` since I am showing 10 entries per page, but results are still incorrect. :*(

Comment: @ChristineCooper Its could be because you need to add the order by meta value to the pagination too... to the `wp_count_terms` BTW as I said before if you already use the `wp_count_terms` used `get_terms` to get all the terms. So you could use `get_terms` instead and then get variables for the pagination and for the php filter.

Comment: That's not the problem. I count the total terms value manually, not via `wp_count_terms`... Did the calculation work on your end?

Comment: @ChristineCooper Oh the problem is not in the `wp_count_terms` its in your loop. You need to order in the loop by the `meta_value`

Comment: How do you mean? Can you please provide me with further notes? Please elaborate on how `get_terms` can be useful here? Since I already have the total terms value... Thanks! EDIT: Note that in my loop, I order by `meta_value`. I use the exact query I provide you above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79087/discussion-between-shibi-and-christine-cooper).